# How to create a new resouce in JSON server in React?

Tags: reactjs, json, api, endpoint, json-server

So I have this on my JSON server now:

```
Resources
http://localhost:8000/taka1008
http://localhost:8000/cheska2389

Home
http://localhost:8000
```

What I want is to create the new Resouces like `http://localhost:8000/example2222`

But with my method below I get this error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')` Also this on web console `POST http://localhost:8000/ 404 (Not Found)`

I used POST method to the Home endpoint:

```
const userIdPost = {userId:[]};  
//userId has a value inside
//Let's say userId = example2222

fetch('http://localhost:8000', {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
   body: JSON.stringify(userIdPost)
}).then(()=>{
   console.log("New user added");
   history.push('/')
})
```

This is what my JSON in my JSON server looks like:

```
{
    "taka1008": [
      {
        "title": "Example1",
        "body": "Empty",
        "body2": "Example",
        "time": "2022-12-16T12:25:51.550Z",
        "commentsArray": [],
        "id": 1
      },
      {
        "title": "Example2",
        "body": "This is a new product and I think we don't have a plan yet. ",
        "body2": "Example",
        "time": "2022-12-16T13:04:40.351Z",
        "commentsArray": [],
        "id": 2
      }
    ],
    "cheska2389": [
      {
        "title": "sada",
        "body": "asd",
        "body2": "sad",
        "time": "2022-12-22T17:55:39.068Z",
        "commentsArray": [],
        "id": 1
      }
    ]
}
```

So when I successfully create the new resource like `http://localhost:8000/example2222`, I am expecting this:

```
{
    "taka1008": [
      {
        "title": "Example1",
        "body": "Empty",
        "body2": "Example",
        "time": "2022-12-16T12:25:51.550Z",
        "commentsArray": [],
        "id": 1
      },
      {
        "title": "Example2",
        "body": "This is a new product and I think we don't have a plan yet. ",
        "body2": "Example",
        "time": "2022-12-16T13:04:40.351Z",
        "commentsArray": [],
        "id": 2
      }
    ],
    "cheska2389": [
      {
        "title": "sada",
        "body": "asd",
        "body2": "sad",
        "time": "2022-12-22T17:55:39.068Z",
        "commentsArray": [],
        "id": 1
      }
    ],
    "example2222": [
      {

      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: is your server runnin on port 8000. can you share your package.json script

Comment: @Yilmaz Sure. I'll edit my post and add it there :)